# Polynomial time algorithm for rigid graph isomorphism

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrices, algorithms

We found, implemented and tested algorithm
for graph isomorphism and it appears to be polynomial
time if the graph is rigid.

> Q1 Is the algorithm below correct and polynomial time for rigid graphs?

A graph is rigid if its automorphism group is trivial.

Two graphs $G_1,G_2$ of order $n$ are isomorphic iff there exist permutation
matrix $P$ such that $P A_1 P^{-1}=P A_1 P^T = A_2$ where $A_1,A_2$ are their
adjacency matrices. We believe it is rigorous to multiply by $P$
and have $P A_1 = A_2 P$.

Let $P$ be $n$ by $n$ matrix with entries $n^2$ variables $x_{i,j}$.

Construct the following system of linear equations $J$.

For the rows $k$ of $P$ add the equations $\sum_{1 \le i \le n} x_{k,i} = 1$.
For the columns $k$ of $P$ add the equations $\sum_{1 \le i \le n} x_{i,k} = 1$.

This is necessary condition $P$ to be permutation and if the variables are zero or one it is
sufficient.

Let $M = P A_1 - A_2 P$. The entries of $M$ are linear equations
in $x_{i,j}$.

For all $n^2$ entries of $M$ add to $J$ the constraints $M_{i,j}=0$.

$J$ has $n^2+2n$ linear equations in $n^2$ variables.

If we can find zero/one solution to $J$, we can solve GI.

Main idea for finding the unique zero/one solution.

Guess variable $x_{i,j}=1$. This forces all $x_{i,k}=0$ for the row
and $x_{k,j}=0$ for the columns. These are $2n$ equations in $2n-1$
variables. Add these equation to $J$ and let the resulting system
be $J'$. Experimentally, if we make the wrong guess in the unique solution,
$J'$ doesn't have any solutions over the rationals and this can be found using linear algebra.
If the guess is wrong, set $x_{i,j}=0$ and substitute in $J$.
If the guess is correct, we might find zero/one solution over the rationals.

Repeat for all $n^2$ variables.

**ADDED** explaining the "guessing" part.
$J$ has infinitely many integer solutions but single zero/one solution
since the graph is rigid. Let $P'$ be the matrix of the unique zero/one solution. We are guessing $P'$ entry by entry. Assume $P'_{1,1}=1$.
In $J'$ add $x_{1,1}=1,x_{1,i}=0,x_{i,1}=0,1 \le i \le n$. This reduces the number
of variables by $2n-1$. Since the guess is correct, we keep the unique
zero/one solution and $J'$ has integer solution. In practice the integer
solution is zero/one over the integers.

Assume we make the wrong guess $P'_{1,2}=1$. Add the rows and columns
constraints $x_{1,2}=1,x_{1,i}=0,x_{i,2}=0,1 \le i \le n$. Experimentally in the wrong guess
$J'$ doesn't have any solutions over the integers and hence no zero/one
solution. In $J$ replace $x_{1,2}=0$ in all equations, decreasing the
variables by $1$

The complexity of the algorithm is polynomial in $n$, probably something
like $O(n^8)$.

Our main pain is that guessing the wrong solution might not be detected
over the rationals or integers.

Comment: "Experimentally, if we make the wrong guess". What does it mean?

Comment: @MarkSapir I edited the guessing part, is it clear now?

Comment: "Experimentally in the wrong guess " still does not make sense.

Comment: @MarkSapir, I think that the sense is "Our empirical observation is that if the guess was incorrect, ..."

Comment: It it supposed to be a proof or a guess bssed on some computation?

Comment: @MarkSapir No, this is not proof, it is empirical guess based on computations. It well could be wrong.

Answer (score 8):

You have reduced the graph isomorphism problem to a 0-1 programming problem. 0-1 programming problems are NP-hard in general, so the question is whether your particular case is an exception. You haven't provided evidence for that. Many simple ideas work nicely for a few random examples, but when faced with carefully chosen hard examples they don't work. My prediction is that $J'$ will have solutions sometimes even when the guess is wrong. I suggest you try strongly-regular graphs.

Comment: Rigid strongly regular graphs are indeed counterexamples to the current algorithm. Tested with a graph of order 36.

Answer (score 4):

It is a long standing open question if graph isomorphism can be solved in polynomial time when the input graphs are rigid. See [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22094/testing-isomorphism-of-asymmetric-graphs/22104), for example.

So, if correct, your algorithm would be a major breakthrough.  I can't seem to follow the guessing step though.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the guessing part, is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks, it is clearer now.  FWIW though, I agree with Brendan McKay that $J'$ will sometimes have solutions even when the guess is wrong.

Comment: Rigid strongly regular graphs are indeed counterexamples to the current algorithm. Tested with a graph of order 36.

Comment: May I have your opinion about [Maximum independent set in dense graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401133/maximum-independent-set-in-dense-graphs)