# Maximum independent set in dense graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Let $0 < A < 1$ and $G$ be connected d-regular graph
with degree $d=[A n]$. The density of $G$ is about $A$.

> Q1 Are there constraints on $A$ such that finding maximum
> independent set of $G$ is polynomial?

> Q2 In case there is artificial construction for NP-hardness,
> assume $G$ is random graph.

Arguments that this may be possible for $A \ge \frac12$.

Assume that $A \ge \frac12$ and you have guessed vertex
$v_0$ in MIS.  From $G$ delete $v_0$ and all $[A n]$ neighbors
of $v_0$. The resulting graph $G'$ is of order
$n' \le [(1-A)n] \le \frac12 n$. So a single guess reduces the number
of vertices by factor of at least $\frac12$. After about $\log_2{n}$ guesses we get an independent set. If the guess is wrong, try another vertex.

We got experimental support for random graphs in sagemath.

The algorithm cliquer solved $A=\frac12$ and $n=10^3$ in 5 minutes
and $n=500$ in 3 seconds.

Our toy implementation works in seconds for $n=50$.

> Q3 How to explain the experimental results?

toy sage implementation:

```
def denseis(G):
    """
    Computes maximum independent set in a dense graph
    """
    if G.is_independent_set():  return G.order()
    m=0
    if not G.is_connected():
        return max([denseis(i) for i in G.connected_components_subgraphs()])
    for v in G.vertices():
        F=G.copy()
        nei=[v]+F.neighbors(v)
        F.delete_vertices(nei)
        m=max(m,1+denseis(F))
    return m

#Compute maximum independent set
sage: set_random_seed(1);n=80;A=2/3;G=graphs.RandomRegular(round(A*n),n)     
sage: time denseis(G)
CPU times: user 2.63 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 2.63 s
Wall time: 2.63 s
6
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "The algorithm cliquer solved"? What was solved?

Comment: @Wolfgang Cliquer solved several random graphs with A=1/2 and n=1000.

Comment: @Wolfgang I edited with example how to compute MIS in a dense graph.

Comment: Your argument may work in random graphs, where neighbourhoods of distinct points are sufficiently independent. However, it does not work in arbitrary $d$-regular graphs. A *single* guess reduces the number of vertices to consider by a factor of $1-A$, yes; but subsequent guesses do not necessarily reduce it any further: for the most extreme example, consider a graph whose complement is a disjoint union of $(1-A)n$-cliques (if, say, $A=1-1/k$ for an integer $k$).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek My implementation works on complements of cliques according to my tests. You can try the sage code locally or in a browser. Would you give explicit graph to test hardness? My algorithm works separately on the connected components if the graph is not connected.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek The algorithm appears to imply the following: assume G is random d-regular graph. Then we can find MIS in one of G or the complement of G in quasi-polynomial time. The hardest cases appear to be the self-complementary graphs with A=1/2  and they can be solved too.

Comment: Here is a counterexample that works. Let $G_0$ and $G_1$ be constant-degree expanders on $n/2$ vertices (e.g., random constant-degree graphs), and let $G$ consist of $G_0\cup G_1$ together with all edges between $G_0$ and $G_1$. This has degree $n/2+O(1)$. After the initial guess, the algorithm is confined to one of $G_0$ and $G_1$. Subsequent guesses only remove $O(1)$ vertices each. Vertex expansion easily implies that until you remove $\Omega(n)$ vertices, the remaining graph has a giant component with $\ge n/4$ vertices. Thus, considering only guesses made inside the giant component, ...

Comment: ...  the algorithm explores at least $(n/4)^{\Omega(n)}$ computation branches.

Comment: (If you insist on degree exactly $n/2$, just delete an appropriate number of edges between $G_0$ and $G_1$. This will only make the running time worse.)

Comment: Concerning random graphs, it is well known that (whp) they only have independent sets and cliques of size $O(\log n)$, hence the maximal ones can be found in time $n^{O(\log n)}$ by brute force (which is basically what your algorithm does).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Many thanks :)) Your last counterexample is indeed computationally infeasible for the algorithm, modulo my bugs.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I gave similar algorithm for MIS which solves your counterexample: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401611/maximum-independent-set-in-dense-graphs-part-2