# Bounds for $a(n)=a(n-1)+a(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, integer-sequences

This is related to problem in graph theory.

OEIS defines [A033485](https://oeis.org/A033485) as

$a(1)=1$ and $a(n)=a(n-1)+a(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$.

> Q1 what are upper bounds and asymptotics for $a(n)$, can we get $\exp(o(n))$?

For real $A,0 < A < 1$ define:

$b(0)=b(1)=1$ and $b(n)=b(n-1)+b(\lfloor A n\rfloor)$

If  $A \le \frac12$ then $b(n) \le a(n)$.

> Q2 what are upper bounds and asymptotics for $b(n)$?

Comment: Numerical evidence appears to suggest $\log{a(n)}=C \log^2{n}$

Answer (score 7):

This recurrence was the subject of one of Donald Knuth's earliest papers!   See
https://tensen.net/research/static/logos/number-theory/partitions-restricted/knuth.pdf .

Comment: Many thanks. Did you notice that Emil solved generalization of a(n)? Also there is graph theoretic problem related to the sequence.

Comment: Very interesting: I was always looking for a really elementary argument for the intermediate growth of the partition function. This gives an elementary lower bound of intermediate growth!

Answer (score 4):

Sure, for each fixed $k$ both of them are (up to a constant) eventually dominated by $c(n)=c(n-1)+c(n-k)$ and this sequence is $O(t^n)$ for $t=t(k)\to 1$ as $k\to \infty$ (one has to prove a simple estimate for the roots of $t^k=t^{k-1}+1$).

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure this is correct. t^n appears to be disproved by experimental evidence. For n=10^3, a(n)<n^4 and this can't be exponential.

Comment: @joro did you see the word **dominated** in my answer? Sure, sequence $n^4$ is dominated by $t^n$ for every $t>1$, I did not claim any lower bounds (though it’s easy to see that your bound $n^4$ or any polynomial bound really can not be true but it’s unrelated to the matter at hand).

Comment: @joro if it’s not clear, I proved the requested $exp(o(n))$ upper bound, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Thanks. It is not clear to me still.

Comment: Ok, once again, slowly. Do you agree that if we define sequence $c(n)$ as in my answer then there’s $C$ (depending on $k$) such that $a(n)\le C c(n)$? Now, do you agree that $c(n)=O(t^n)$? These two statements give us $a(n)=O(t^n)$ for arbitrary $t>1$. This is the same as being $exp(o(n))$

Comment: Thanks. Do you have asymptotics as edited?

Comment: As edited where?

Comment: Edited in the question.

Comment: Well, you changed your question from something rather easy (upper bounds) to a much harder one (asymptotics). I don’t know the answer to the later one.

Comment: I still don't understand what is $o(n)$ in your answer. I expect something like $\exp(\sqrt{n})$ or $\exp(\log(n)^2)$.

Comment: Well, it is something. You can in principle extract it from my proof but I’m not up to doing it, it looks straightforward but tedious.

Comment: You are writing Big Oh and I am asking about **small oh**. Is there confusion?

Comment: @joro If $a(n) \in O(t^n)$, then it is also $o(s^n)$ for any $s > t$. Therefore, if $a(n) \in O(t^n)$ for all $t > 1$, it is also $o(t^n)$ for all $t > 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Set $a_k(1)=r_k$ and $a_k(n)=a_k(n-1)+2^k a_k(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)$ for $n\geq 2$
where $r_0=1$ and $r_k=a_{k-1}(2)=(1+2^{k-1})r_{k-1}\leq 2^kr_{k-1}$.

We have $a_0(n)=a(n)$ for $a(n)$ defined by the OP.

An easy induction shows $a_k(2n),a_k(2n+1)\leq a_{k+1}(n)$.

We get thus $$a(n)=a_0(n)\leq a_1(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)\leq a_2(\lfloor n/4\rfloor)\leq \ldots\leq a_{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}(1)=r_{\lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor}\ .$$

Using $r_k\leq 2^k r_{k-1}\leq 2^{k+(k-1)}r_{k-2}\leq\ldots$, we get finally
$$a(n)\leq 2^{1+2+\ldots+\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}\sim \sqrt{2}^{(\log_2 n)^2}$$
as observed by the OP.

Comment: Many thanks :))

Comment: It is true that $1+2+\ldots+\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor$ is asymptotic to $(\log_2 n)^2/2$, but it is not true that $2^{1+2+\ldots+\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}$ is asymptotic to $2^{(\log_2 n)^2/2}$. Exponentiation is sensitive.

Comment: I agree with GH, it gives however the correct logarithmic asymptotic for the lower bound. Moreover, my upper bounds $r_k\leq 2^kr_{k-1}$ are rather savage ($r_k\sim 2^{k-1}r_{k-1}$ asymptotically) and overcompensate asymptotically the previous error.

Answer (score 4):

Confirming the numerical evidence, the $b(n)$ sequences have rate of growth
$$b(n)=n^{\Theta(\log n)}.$$

On the one hand, since $b(n)$ is nondecreasing, we have
$$\begin{align}b(n)&=b(\lfloor An\rfloor)+b(n-1)\\
&\le2b(\lfloor An\rfloor)+b(n-2)\\
&\le\cdots\\
&\le(n-1)b(\lfloor An\rfloor)+b(1)\\
&\le nb(\lfloor An\rfloor).
\end{align}$$
Since it takes at most $(\log n)/\log A^{-1}$ iterations of $n\mapsto\lfloor An\rfloor$ to get from $n$ down to $1$, we obtain
$$b(n)\le n^{C\log n},\qquad C=(\log A^{-1})^{-1}.$$

On the other hand, we have, say,
$$b(n)\ge\frac n2b(\lfloor An/2\rfloor)$$
by the same argument, which easily yields
$$b(n)=\Omega(n^{c\log n})$$
for any $c<\frac12\log\frac2A$.

Comment: Many thanks. Would you please elaborate the transition to b(n)<=n^(C log(n))? Are you using this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401203/bounds-for-the-sequence-an-a-na-lfloor-1-an-rfloor-a?rq=1

Comment: Which part of it is unclear? The final step just uses that it takes $(\log n)/\log A^{-1}$ iterations of $b(n)\le n b(An)$ to get from $n$ down to $1$, thus $b(n)$ is bounded by the product of $(\log n)/\log A^{-1}$ many $n$’s.

Comment: FYI: did you see Shallit's answer that this is one Knuth earliest papers?

Answer (score 1):

Philippe Dumas has work deriving very precise asymptotic results for 'divide-and-conquor' sequences such as this. For instance, see 'Asymptotic expansions for linear homogeneous divide-and-conquer recurrences: Algebraic and analytic approaches collated' from 2014 (https://specfun.inria.fr/dumas/Publications/Dumas14.pdf).

Comment: Many thanks and welcome to mathoverflow.