# Bounds for the sequence $a(n)=a(n-1)+a(\lfloor n-n^A \rfloor)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

Related to the [question about a(n)=a(n-1)+a(floor(n/2))](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401272/bounds-for-an-an-1a-lfloor-n-2-rfloor)

Let $A$ be real constant $ 0 < A < 1$.

Define the sequence $a(n)$ by $a(1)=1, a(n)=a(n-1)+a(\lfloor n-n^A \rfloor)$

(if you prefer take $a'(n)=a'(n-1)+a'(n-\lfloor n^A \rfloor)$.

> Q1 What are bounds for $a(n)$, especially good upper bound?

If you prefer take $A=\frac12$.

We could't find the sequence in OEIS for $A=\frac12$.

We are interested if we can get $a(n)=\exp(o(n))$ (small oh on purpose).

**ADDED** As Iosif Pinelis points out, we must define $a(0)$, so
we define $a(0)=1$.

Comment: It certainly doesn't grow slower than *any* linear recurrence with constant coefficients, since e.g. $b(n)=2b(n-1)-b(n-2)$ grows linearly. I'm assuming you meant positive constant coefficients or something like that. This is equivalent to an $\exp(o(n))$ bound.

Comment: @Wojowu  Thanks, you are right!. I forgot about degenerate linear recurrences :(

Comment: It is certainly true that $e^{\epsilon n}>e^{\epsilon(n-1)} + e^{\epsilon(n-\sqrt n)}$ for all positive $\epsilon$ and all large $n$, so the growth must be sub-exponential.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thanks. Would you please give citable answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us show that
\begin{equation*}
    a(n)\le\exp(n^{1-A+o(1)}) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
(as $n\to\infty$).

Indeed, for each $q\in(1-A,1)$,
\begin{equation*}
    (k-1)^q-k^q\sim-qk^{q-1},\quad (k-k^A)^q-k^q\sim-qk^{A+q-1}
\end{equation*}
(as $k\to\infty)$, so that
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\exp((k-1)^q)+\exp((k-k^A)^q)}{\exp(k^q)} \\ 
    =1-(q+o(1))k^{q-1}+\exp(-(q+o(1))k^{A+q-1})
\end{equation*}
and hence
\begin{equation*}
    \exp((k-1)^q)+\exp((k-k^A)^q)\le\exp(k^q) \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
for some natural $K_{A,q}$ (depending only on $A,q$) and for all natural $k\ge K_{A,q}$.

Next, there exists a real $C_{A,q}>0$ depending only on $A,q$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    a(n)\le C_{A,q}\exp(n^q) \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}
for all $n\in\{0,\dots,K_{A,q}-1\}$. Suppose that \eqref{3} holds for some natural $k\ge K_{A,q}$ and all $n\in\{0,\dots,k-1\}$.
Then
\begin{equation*}
    a(k)=a(k-1)+a(\lfloor k-k^A\rfloor)\\ 
    \le C_{A,q}\exp((k-1)^q)+C_{A,q}\exp((k-k^A)^q)\big)
    \le C_{A,q}\exp(k^q) 
\end{equation*}
by \eqref{2}. So, \eqref{3} continues to hold for $n=k$. So, by induction on $n$, \eqref{3} holds for all natural $n$, if $q\in(1-A,1)$. This completes the proof of \eqref{1}.

---

If $a(0)\ge0$, then one can similarly obtain the corresponding lower bound on $a(n)$, to get
\begin{equation*}
    a(n)=\exp(n^{1-A+o(1)}) 
\end{equation*}
(as $n\to\infty$).

---

Working a bit harder, we can get
\begin{equation*}
    a(n)=\exp(n^{1-A}\ln^{1+o(1)}n) 
\end{equation*}
(as $n\to\infty$). Such refinements can apparently go ad infinitum.

Anyhow, the requested bound $\exp o(n)$ on $a(n)$ has certainly been obtained.

Comment: Is it possible that you are missing a logarithmic factor?. For A=1/2 i get log(a(n))/n^(1-A) steadily increasing for some n up to n=15000.

Comment: @joro : The proof is very simple, and I do not see anything missing there. Do you? However, the result is that $a(n)=\exp(n^{1-A+o(1)})$, that is, $\dfrac{\ln a(n)}{n^{1-A}}=n^{o(1)}$, and certainly the latter expression can in general grow faster than any power of $\ln n$. So, the result is somewhat crude, as only the constant $1-A$ in the exponent $1-A+o(1)$ of the exponent $n^{1-A+o(1)}$ of $a(n)=\exp(n^{1-A+o(1)})$ is presently asserted to be optimal. Yet, this result is of course enough to get the requested bound $\exp o(n)$.

Comment: Previous comment continued: One can also refine the bound $a(n)=\exp(n^{1-A+o(1)})$, perhaps ad infinitum, but then the answer would be perhaps too long for MO.

Comment: Previous comment continued: I have now detailed $n^{o(1)}$ as $\ln^{1+o(1)}n$.

Comment: Technical comment: Mathjax does not render the \fl command for me. It seems to not understand \newcommand.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay : This command is no longer used.

Comment: Many thanks. :)

Comment: @joro : You are welcome.